# How to turn on and off aeroplane mode via termux-api?

Tags: linux, termux

I had  checked this

https://github.com/termux/termux-api/issues/138
but no use

Answer (score 0):

Changing the state of the Airplane Mode Settings toggle is facilitated by a Special Android API which accesses and Modifies System Settings, which is NOT a part of Termux. Until the devs themselves introduce a command to do so, you will need superuser i.e. root privileges to do so. I hope the `svc` commands will help.